# PHP & Languages - Query DB for Japanese & Display in HTML

Tags: php, mysql

This is the first time I've worked with Japanese.

I have a MySQL Database that is now holding Japanese successfully using CHARSET=utf8

When I use PHP to Query the table with Japanese and then display the text it shows up like:

```
 \u30b7\u30f3\u30b0\u30eb\u30b9\u3092\u6e80\u305f\u3059
```

The Database connect is using this:

```
  SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI';
```

Should this be changed.
Also the language text is being pasted using CURL. 
Do I need to encode/decode the language to transfer it like this?

thankyou

Comment: webpage is set to <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>

Answer (score 0):

To use UTF successfully, your **ENTIRE** web pipeline must be UTF. That means:

a) the web page itself
b) The PHP<->mysql connection
c) any string operations inside PHP (e.g. use mbstrlen() instead of strlen())
d) The tables inside mysql

if you use a different character set anywhere in that pipeline, your utf data will get corrupted and trashed.